# Using Google Transit APIs in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I want to use Google Transit API in Android application. But I am getting data from service. I used the following parameters:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343605500&mode=transit

I always get this response:

```
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I think I am passing something wrong in any of parameters used in above URL, maybe `departure_time` is wrong?

Can anyone tell what should pass to parameters?
Can anyone help me to find out URL with such parameters which return value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to set departure_time parameter to some time in future (like several days). From [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/):

> When requesting transit directions, be sure to specify either a
>   departure_time or arrival_time. Note that in this example the
>   departure time is specified as July 30, 2012 at 09:45 am. Update the
>   parameter to a point in the future before submitting the request.

Try http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1350472557&mode=transit, it works.

Comment: How did you calculate time - " 1350472557 " ? What is actual time ?

Comment: It is [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). There are a lot of online convertors.